# How can I add more images to my HTML5/CSS3 Slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

How to add more images to this slideshow. When ever I add more than 4 images it ignores the images after 4th image. And what do I need to change when I add new images. I want to add around 15 images. Or how can I randomise the source of the images so they will be different every time.

HTML:
            
                
                
                    
                        
                        The mirror of soul
                    
                        
                        Let's cross that bridge when we come to it
                    
                        
                        Sushi*(do)* time
                    
                        
                        shit
                    
                        
                        Waking Life

```
        <span id="timeline"></span>

        <ul class="dots_commands"><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 1" href="#sl_i1">Slide 1</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 2" href="#sl_i2">Slide 2</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 3" href="#sl_i3">Slide 3</a></li><!--
            --><li><a title="Show slide 4" href="#sl_i4">Slide 4</a></li>
        </ul>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

css is to Long so its on this link:  http://jsfiddle.net/3p4vu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands you have to change slides are unnecessary and confusing.

All you need is a simple use of `$(...).prev()` and `$(...).next()` on your current image selector. A check would be needed to detect end of or beginning of since you want this double-ended.

Fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/9fP59/
You'll need to expand and style to how you like, but having many different next/previous buttons is the wrong way.

With more boxes to demonstrate how extensible this method is: http://jsfiddle.net/9fP59/2/

Basing it off of this fiddle you can change the `.prev()` and `.next()` selector to work off of the same function with a random element selector with:

```
var random = Math.round(Math.random() * $('.image').length),
    element = $('.image').eq(random);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is way easier and simpler method.